# Dropdown já selecionado

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dropdown

Fiz um dropdown com AngularJs da seguinte maneira

```
<ui-select ng-model="SelectedItem.LegalEntity" 
            theme="bootstrap"
            reset-search-input="false"
            style="width: 100%"
            id="legalEntityId"
            ng-disabled="disabled">
           <ui-select-match placeholder="">{{$select.selected.Name}}</ui-select-match>
               <ui-select-choices repeat="entity in legalEntities">
                <div ng-bind-html="entity.Name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
               </ui-select-choices>
           </ui-select>
```

Quando o dropdown tiver somente 1 item na lista, quero bloquear o dropdown e deixar o primeiro item já selecionado.

Já consigo bloquear usando o ng-disable, mas não consegui carregar a página com o primeiro item do dropdown selecionado.

Comment: um working fiddle era baril para ser mais facil. De qualquer maneira, o `ui-select` não tem uma propriedade `selected` ? se sim, supostamente o `ng-selected="expression"` devia ser suficiente

Comment: eu uso o  <ui-select-choices repeat="entity in legalEntities">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para pré-carregar o ui-select com algum valor basta atribuir a lista a variável do ng-model no controller:

```
var legalEntities = [{Name: 'nameDaEntity'}];

$scope.SelectedItem.LegalEntity = legalEntities;
```